# HEVC Intel QuickSync not working: Error loading plugins | Could not load the requested plugin

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, hardware-acceleration

I am able to encode to h264 using Intel QuickSync just fine:

```
ffmpeg -init_hw_device qsv=hw -i IN.MKV -c:a copy -c:v h264_qsv OUT.MP4
```

I used this command for HEVC:

```
ffmpeg -load_plugin hevc_hw -init_hw_device qsv=hw -filter_hw_device hw -i IN.MOV -c:a copy -c:v hevc_qsv OUT.MP4
```

But it errors:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> hevc (hevc_qsv))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[hevc_qsv @ 000002eb19cb75c0] Could not load the requested plugin '25ca997f46db6894b123ef9f1a5baef7': specified object was not found (-9)
[hevc_qsv @ 000002eb19cb75c0] Error loading plugins
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

My CPU is: Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ Processor

It's a 6th Generation Skylake https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/88967/intel-core-i76700hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html

And from what I gathered about QuickSync, it supports HEVC encoding/decoding:

> Version 5 (Skylake) The Skylake microarchitecture adds a full
> fixed-function H.265/HEVC main/8-bit encoding and decoding
> acceleration, hybrid and partial HEVC main10/10-bit decoding
> acceleration, JPEG encoding acceleration for resolutions up to
> 16,000×16,000 pixels, and partial VP9 encoding and decoding
> acceleration.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Quick_Sync_Video

So I believe my CPU is supported since FFMPEG's documentation also says that: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync

When I decode with this command:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel qsv -c:v hevc_qsv -i x265.mp4 -f NULL -
```

I get these errors:

```
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Function not implemented
[hevc_qsv @ 000002624c781ac0] Could not load the requested plugin '15dd936825ad475ea34e35f3f54217a6': specified object was not found (-9)
[hevc_qsv @ 000002624c781ac0] Error loading plugins
[hevc_qsv @ 000002624c781ac0] Error initializing an MFX session
```

How do I resolve the errors?

Comment: I had forgotten to update my FFMPEG, I was using: `ffmpeg-4.1.3-win64-static` Updated to this and the issue seems to be resolved: `ffmpeg-5.1-full_build`